# Why am I getting an input Invalid Infinite Loop?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop, inputmismatchexception

Why does this cause me to get stuck in an endless loop when the initial choice is invalid?

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Choice:\t");
    try {
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Choice: df
Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
Choice: Invalid Input!
```

Comment: You have to put `break` in `finally` clause.

Comment: A `break` in the `catch` clause would do. But what is the purpose of the `while (true)` loop, then?

Comment: Put `break` in `catch` clasue also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> When a scanner throws an [InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html), the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

So the `"df"` string is still in the Scanner. You have to clear it somehow, by calling `next()` or some other means.

Comment: +1 for official JavaDoc reference and explaining *why*.

Comment: Thanks this has been bothering me for some time.

Answer (score 4):

Scanner is trying to parse and return the same token over and over again (and it's not integer, so it's throwing an exception). You could fix it by discarding invalid token:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Choice:\t");
    try {
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
        scanner.next();                         // here, discard invalid token.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You break while statement in only in try clause. When your while loop enters in catch, it just doesn't break the loop.

```
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Choice:\t");
  try {
    int choice = scanner.nextInt();
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
  }
  finally {
   break;
  }
}
```